# How to send logging to log files?

Tags: ros, c++, logger

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have logging in my cpp files, like the following, and I'm trying to get the messages to appear in a file.

```
ROS_INFO_STREAM("testing");
```

I have these env vars to show where the logs should be placed, and how to config logging.

```
ROS_LOG_DIR = /tmp/node/etc/logs
ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE = /tmp/node/etc/rosconsole.config
```

And within the rosconsole.config file I have the following.

```
log4j.logger.ros=DEBUG
```

Any thoughts as to why I don't see my output in log files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254986/how-to-send-logging-to-log-files?/) by [SRD](https://answers.ros.org/users/27821/srd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you should define it in the config file, like this

log4j.logger.ros.log_test=WARN,rosout_a
log4j.appender.rosout_a=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rosout_a.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.rosout_a.Append=true
log4j.appender.rosout_a.File=/home/name/output.txt

---

Originally posted by [rjosodtssp](https://answers.ros.org/users/38070/rjosodtssp/) with karma: 28 on 2018-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0